# CanCan - checking permissions inside a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im starting here with cancan and i would like to know how can i check for permissions inside a model or the best way to achieve what i want that is:

In my User form i have checkboxes for roles assignment but only Admins can do that. i Already hide the checkboxes in the html with <% if can? :assign_roles, @user %> but a bad intentioned user may edit the html and add the checkboxes and choose wich role he wants.

So i decided to use a before_save method to check whether the current_user can assign roles but i dont have access to can? method inside models.

Is there a better way to make this verification?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/ability-for-other-users) to archive your goal. So you will be able to use `can?` and `cannot?` methods inside your models in your model context.